# Ambiguous template binary operators?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, std, ambiguous

Consider the following code

```
namespace std {
    struct type1 {/* Definition */};
    template <class T> constexpr T operator+(const type1& x1, const T& x);
    template <class T> constexpr T operator+(const T& x, const type1& x1);
}

namespace other {
    struct type2 {/* Definition */};
    template <class T> constexpr T operator+(const type2& x2, const T& x);
    template <class T> constexpr T operator+(const T& x, const type2& x2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::type1 var1;
    other::type2 var2;
    auto x = var1 + var2; // What will happen here?
}
```

- What would happen on the line `auto x = var1 + var2`?
- Is that a defined behaviour or not?
- And does that mean that the standard library would never define generic operators with a template on only one side to avoid conflicting use?

Comment: As for "what will happen" why don't you first try it and tell us?

Comment: @101010 They're not anymore

Comment: Is that purely academic (not that there is anything wrong with that), or do you have a usecase in mind?

Comment: @xophos The question I have in mind is the following: could the standard committee ever standardize a binary operator overload where one side is a std:: class, and where the other side is an unconstrained template type?

Comment: @xophos Without a constraint I cannot see how a meaningful implementation could possibly be provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [depended name look up](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (a.k.a Koenig Lookup) rules which are well defined. The compiler will lookup function names in the namespaces of the `operator+` arguments in addition to the scopes and namespaces considered by the usual unqualified name lookup.

Thus, the compiler is going to add to the overload set both the matching overloaded operators (i.e., from namespaces `std` and `other`).

Consequently, you'll get an ambiguous call error.

Answer (score 1):

You should get an ambiguous operator error on conforming compilers. 
Your program is **ill formed** since both versions of overload qualify as candidates.

Answer (score -1):

This code causes undefined behaviour. It is not permitted to add your own things to `namespace std;`, other than explicit specializations of existing templates.

Comment: This is a correct but useless answer that completely fails to address what the OP means to ask. This could have been useful as a comment though.

Comment: @hvd maybe you could enlighten us by editing the question to reflect what you think OP means to ask

Comment: The question already makes perfect sense. Just pretend the OP used `STD` instead of `std`; the question is not about user code adding types to the `std` namespace.

Comment: @hvd In that case, the answer to the third bullet is "the standard library  would never define operators in namespace `STD`" ... which (also?) seems correct but useless

Comment: The question asks in bullet points 1 and 2 what happens in case multiple types in different namespaces have template operators defined for them. (The different namespaces may or may not be relevant.) The question asks in bullet point 3 whether the standard will have / has template operators for that reason. Of course user code would not use the `std` namespace, and standard library code would.

Comment: I think this answer needs to be upvoted to the top. Deterring people from adding code to namespace `std` is arguably a more fundamental lesson than teaching about overload ambiguities.